# Uso e significato della locuzione "punto fermo" in senso figurato

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Sono andata ad ascoltare una conferenza tenuta da un italiano che lavora come editore di una piccola casa editrice a Barcellona. A un certo momento ha usato l'espressione "punto fermo" riferendosi a una persona. Purtroppo non sono in grado di riprodurre la frase esatta da lui pronunciata, ma questa locuzione ha attirato la mia attenzione perché ne conoscevo soltanto il senso letterale. Ho ricercato in parecchi dizionari e l'unico riferimento a questo senso figurato che sono riuscita a trovare è stato nel [dizionario De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/punto-fermo) che la definisce come "certezza, sicurezza", facendo questo esempio:

> il lavoro era il **punto fermo** della sua vita

Potreste spiegarmi in quali situazioni si può usare questa espressione in senso figurato, dandone esempi, alcuno dei quali si riferisca a una persona?

Comment: Bisognerebbe sapere come fosse formulata la frase, ma a naso direi che quella persona era sempre presente e di fondamentale importanza per la casa editrice o per un progetto di cui parlava.

Answer (score 2):

Nel contesto da te citato punto fermo significa riferimento, una cosa importante e fondamentale nella vita del personaggio.

Da Treccani per ***punto fermo***:

> [punto fermo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/punto1_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/) [posizione raggiunta o fissata: *la sua partecipazione
>   all'affare è un p. fermo*] ≈ certezza, sicurezza.

E, ad esempio:

> Per il sindacato il salario minimo è il ***punto fermo*** da cui far partire
>   la trattativa

dove qui indica un qualcosa di stabilito ed inamovibile senza cui la trattativa non prosegue.

> Il sindaco ha fatto della legalità il ***punto fermo*** del suo mandato.

anche qui come elemento, comportamento ineludibile durante l'esercizio della sua carica.

Comment: Più che "contesto da me citato", ho semplicemente riportato quello che dice il dizionario De Mauro.

Comment: Quando ho scritto che si riferiva a una persona volevo dire che era qualcosa tipo "tale persona è un punto fermo".

Comment: Quale “personaggio”?

Comment: @DaG: Infatti, la conferenza non è stata propriamente sulla casa editrice,  ma su Giorgio Bassani (l'italiano che l'ha fatta è un ferrarese che conosce personalmente Paola Bassani, la figlia dello scrittore). Penso che la persona a cui si riferisse l'espressione "punto fermo" fosse appunto Giorgio Bassani.